# How can I color specific parts of the rsync output?

Tags: sed, grep, rsync, colors

I run this command to rsync some files from Windows (Cygwin) to my local NAS:

```
rsync -PaSq --delete -e "/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/bin/ssh -i keyfile -p XXXX" "/source/" admin@192.168.1.1:/destination/
```

I now want to highlight in red any error messages. By that I mean highlighting the errors from rsync once it connects and not the ssh connection errors.

So this ssh connection error message remains unchanged:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

But this is highlighted in red:

```
rsync: delete_file: unlink(test/test.txt) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I've tried the following with no luck.
Any ideas appreciated.

```
rsync -PaSq --delete -e "/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/bin/ssh -i keyfile -p XXXX" "/source/" admin@192.168.1.1:/destination/ | tput setaf 1; sed -n '/rsync:/p'

rsync -PaSq --delete -e "/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/bin/ssh -i keyfile -p XXXX" "/source/" admin@192.168.1.1:/destination/ | egrep --color '.*rsync:.*|$'

rsync -PaSq --delete -e "/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/bin/ssh -i keyfile -p XXXX" "/source/" admin@192.168.1.1:/destination/ | grep --color=auto '.*rsync:.*|$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face comes from the fact that `rsync` outputs errors to *the standard error* (file descriptor 2), but the pipe by default transfers only *the standard output* (file descriptor 1), leaving standard error untouched. So the command after the pipe (`sed` or `grep` in your example) doesn't see errors which came from `rsync`.

You can redirect both stdout and stderr using `|&` aka `2>&1 |`. Another approach is to redirect only stderr, leavng stdout where it pointed, so try something like:

```
rsync ... |& grep --color '.*rsync:.*'
```

or

```
{ rsync ...  2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep --color '.*rsync:.*' 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

Second approach is a little bit complicated because we need to temporarily redirect stdout somewhere (to descriptor `3` in this case) in order to **not** pass it to the `grep`.